# Why does the Google Oauth2 consent form display company URL instead of product name?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-developers-console

[image]

This just my local test page.

is there some parameter to show my product name ?

https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/oauthchooseaccount?client_id=750613625541-ju0p2hvmml1eahjmt9l4f01gdtp9s33o.apps.googleusercontent.com&as=-2201fc670d7b92ee&nosignup=1&destination=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.storage.com&approval_state=!ChRxdl9WYmw4YURnUWxCemhGSTFUZRIfMC1LRl90bTZ2Z2NaWUg3R0Q2SDQtRUVFOEJjeHpoVQ%E2%88%99ADiIGyEAAAAAWVH50eZlchIgJ3-_vV2dZuQUMH9bhmmI&passive=1209600&ltmpl=nosignup&oauth=1&sarp=1&scc=1&xsrfsig=AHgIfE_ysFUz37usqpUy0VanY6KxOc5Kkg&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

This is the url of authorization in my App.

Answer (score 0):

This used to be possible as a is a setting in the [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent).

Google developer console -> credentials -> Oauth consent screen tab

[image]

Google has been making a number of changes to the OAuth consent form recently. This is a direct consequence of the Gmail phishing hack a few months ago.  One of the changes is as you see it the website of the application is now being displayed instead of the application name.  This it was thought would be easier for users to understand WHO they are granting access to their data rather than what application has access to their data.  This is not something you can change.

Comment: OK.I have set product name shown to users on Oauth consent screen tab.But not show product name also.I hope can display this,even a small place.

Comment: These changes are a work in progress i have already sent feedback that they should add name back and include the url as well.   Have you tried clicking on the url?  what does that do?

Comment: The url just analysis from redirect url.If i didn'n deal with that,that not working,just tell user which domain they are authorized.

Comment: Sounds about right. There is nothing you can do to change it at this time.  Like i said Google isn't done with these changes they are getting feed back from developers all he time.   I pinged someone on the identity platform team he may or may not reply to your question.  If he does he can probably give you more information on if this will be adjusted in the future.