# How to show our custom domain on Google sign-in?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We have a web app with  Firebase, and we already connected our custom domain, and can access the website with `www.example.com`.

Problem: when user is sign in user Gmail, he see this on Google's page :

**"Sign in to project-60017.firebaseapp.com"**

instead of

**Sign in to example.com**

Even that this app is already connected and working with example.com.

We initializing the app with :

```
              authDomain: "project-60017.firebaseapp.com",
              databaseURL: "https://project-60017.firebaseio.com",
              projectId: "project-60017",
              storageBucket: "project-60017.appspot.com",
              messagingSenderId: "75892xxxxxx"
```

If I try to change these URLs to `example.com` nothing will work anymore.

How to make users that sign in to see `example.com` (our own domain) ?

**EDIT**:

If i change this :     `authDomain: "example.com",` in the project setup, i will get a redirect error when signin :

```
The redirect uri in the request .../auth/handler does not match the ones autorized for the OAtuh
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the app name for firebase authentication (what the user sees)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135993/how-to-change-the-app-name-for-firebase-authentication-what-the-user-sees)

Comment: possible, but not a duplicate because the answer is about facebook auth, not gmail.

Comment: Question was edited.

Answer (score 7):

To anyone who is trying, I just changed `Authorized redirect URIs` in the Google Cloud Console.

I have added this record :

```
https://example.com/__/auth/handler
```

When you add it, don't click save, first click Enter,  then save. (otherwise it won't be saved and that was my problem).

Then in the Firebase app itself - you have to set:

```
authDomain: "example.com",
```

and then you see your domain on log in.

Comment: the url for the Google Clous is : https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials