# Change the app name for Firebase authentication

Tags: angular, firebase, google-authentication

In  web, ios and android  app we are using Firebase Auth to manage logins and (basic) account creation. I am trying to display the name of my website on google auth popup. When prompted to login, it says "Sign in to continue to my-real-appname-12345f.firebaseapp.com."

How to I change that to our customize name ?

I'm already try to change Public-facing name of firebase settings > General tab but it not works for me.

But our mobile app google login popups shows app name correctly. [ios auth login popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xD4p.jpg)

But our web application shows "my-real-appname-12345f.firebaseapp.com." instead of app name

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Did you see [How to change the app name for Firebase authentication (what the user sees)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135993/how-to-change-the-app-name-for-firebase-authentication-what-the-user-sees)? "not works for me" is really difficult to help with. As that process is pretty well established, edit your question to show exactly what you did at each step in the process. Also see: [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).